# Unable to get Java Response in Ajax with dataType: "jsonp" but dataType: "text" Works

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am unable to get the Callback response value in ajax when i use the following code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: apiurl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: jsonstring,    
    success: function(response)
    {                 
        callback(response);
        token = response;                
    },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Not Permitted  ' + textStatus);
    }
```

But when i change the above   dataType: "text"  it works.

How to get response when i use dataType:"jsonp".

My java response is as follows:

return Response.status(200).entity("HAI").build();

Any help should be greatly apprecited.

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(response)` in the success part?

Comment: if you want make dataType:"jsonp" to work, then your response (from server side page) must be json encoded string and not a plain text !

Comment: actually success part is not working.Always failure is called.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jsonp it seems no need to set contentType: 'application/json', because it is actually a piece of javascript instead of json string.